# Error pushing to heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

When I push my rails 4 app to heroku (`git push -f heroku master`) everything works fine except the following error messages. Any idea what these are and how i can fix them? Thanks.

```
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (1.01s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/README.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Rakefile': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/History.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/Manifest.txt': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_mock.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/metametameta.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_unit.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_spec.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/test/minitest/test_minitest_benchmark.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/hoe/minitest.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/spec.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/benchmark.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/hell.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/autorun.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/pride.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/mock.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/design_rationale.rb': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/app/tmp/cache/cedar/vendor/bundle/./ruby/2.0.0/gems/minitest-4.7.5/.autotest': Permission denied
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 33.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v76
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it just started today. I bet it's a Heroku issue. I think it's harmless for now.

Comment: I get the same error. Must be a Heroku thing.

Comment: Me too, we don't want a copy of minitest anyway...  I will note that I'm getting the wrong version of ruby printed ( I'm running 2.1.1 and it displays an error for 2.1.0 )

Comment: Definitely a heroku thing, just happened to me too for the first time.

Comment: Also seeing this now. We are deploying our site anyway, crossing fingers!